# Solve the following equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I have this equation $\hat{5}x = \hat{6}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$. I'm not good at all at modular arithemetic. So far I just figured it out that $\hat{5}x = 6+16k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Note: $x=\hat{6}\cdot\hat{5}^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$, Compute modular inverse of $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$

Comment: Well $5x=6+16k$ is a good start. You need $16k$ to be a multiple of 5 plus 4, so trying $k=1,2,3,4$, you find that $6+16\cdot4=70$, so $x=14$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve the congruence $5x \equiv 6 \pmod{16}$ by first finding the multiplicative inverse of $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ to determine the value of $x$ that satisfies the congruence $5x \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$, then multiplying both sides of the congruence by $6$.

Since $\gcd(5, 16) = 1$, $5$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$.  We can find the inverse by applying the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).
$$16 = 3 \cdot 5 + 1$$
Solving for $1$ yields 
$$1 = 16 - 3 \cdot 5$$
Hence, 
$$-3 \cdot 5 \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$$
Thus, $5^{-1} \equiv -3 \equiv -3 + 16 \equiv 13 \pmod{16}$, so we may write 
$$13 \cdot 5 \equiv 1 \pmod{16}$$
If we multiply both sides of the congruence by $6$, we obtain
$$78 \cdot 5 \equiv 6 \pmod{16}$$
Since $78 \equiv 78 - 4 \cdot 16 \equiv 14 \pmod{16}$, we obtain
$$14 \cdot 5 \equiv 6 \pmod{16}$$
Hence, the solution to the congruence 
$$5x \equiv 6 \pmod{16}$$
is 
$$x \equiv 14 \pmod{16}$$
**Check:** $5 \cdot 14 \equiv 70 \equiv 4 \cdot 16 + 6 \equiv 6 \pmod{16}$.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The basic procedure for solving linear modular equations in $\mathbb{Z}_{N}$ has the following form:

Suppose given an arbitrary linear equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{N}$:
$$
ax = c\text{ in }\mathbb{Z}_{16}
$$
Then the solution is $x = ca^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ (Which follows from the definition of the inverse itself: $a^{-1}a\text{ in }\mathbb{Z}_{16}=1$). To compute an inverse of $a$ you can use Euler's theorem:
$$
x^{\phi(N)}\text{ in }\mathbb{Z}_{N} = 1
$$
if $gcd(x,N) = 1$ (Note that $gcd(5,16)=1$) and where $\phi(N)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), thus the inverse is:
$$
x^{\phi(N)-1}\text{ in } \mathbb{Z}_{N} = x^{-1}\text{ in }\mathbb{Z}_{N}
$$
Thus the solution becomes:
$$
x = ca^{\phi(16)-1}\text{ in } \mathbb{Z}_{16}
$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we are able to divide any number by $\hat{5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ since $5$ is relatively prime to $16$.

Knowing this, the simplest way to discover the value of $x$ is to make a multiplication table showing only the multiples of $5 \pmod{16}$. Starting the table,

> $5 \cdot 0 \equiv 0$
>   $5 \cdot 1 \equiv 5$
>   $5 \cdot 2 \equiv 10$
>   $5 \cdot 3 \equiv 15$
>   $5 \cdot 4 \equiv 4$
>   $\ldots$

You will discover that there is a unique value, $x$, for which $5x$ is congruent to $6 \pmod{16}$. This is your answer.

Comment: You might find this [formatting tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful.